# oozie REST api POST new hive job gets "This request requires HTTP authentication."

Tags: hadoop, authentication, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I'm using REST api to submit HIVE job to oozie.
I tried using postman and curl to send the request but I'm getting an error saying :  **"This request requires HTTP authentication. "**

I tried to run it on my Cloudera quickstart and on Hortonworks but got the same error.

the config.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration><property><name>fs.default.name</name><value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value></property><property><name>mapred.job.tracker</name><value>localhost:8021</value></property><property><name>user.name</name><value>cloudera</value></property><property><name>oozie.hive.script</name><value>select * from test;</value></property><property><name>oozie.libpath</name><value>hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/share/lib/hive</value></property><property><name>oozie.proxysubmission</name><value>true</value></property></configuration>
```

The curl is : 

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @config.xml http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start
```

I tried also this :


```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @config.xml  --negotiate -u cloudera:cloudera //localhost:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start
```

or this: 

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "fs.default.namehdfs://localhost:8020mapred.job.trackerlocalhost:8021user.nameclouderaoozie.hive.scriptselect * from test;oozie.libpathhdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/share/lib/hiveoozie.proxysubmissiontrue"//localhost:11000/oozie/v2/job
```


(the config is correct xml file )

and the response is :

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 - Error report HTTP Status 401 - type Status reportmessage description This request requires HTTP authentication.Apache Tomcat/6.0.44
```

when running a GET request without adding additional authorizations I'm getting the response


```
 curl -X GET "http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/admin/status"
```


and the response: 

```
{"systemMode":"NORMAL"}
```

**what am I missing? 
How should I submit an oozie hive job via the oozie REST api?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution involved fixing the `oozie.wf.application.path` parameter value -- it was pointing to a non existing `workflow.xml` file. Changing this to the correct filename fixed the issue.

I have to admit Oozie's API message in this case wasn't very helpful: `This request requires HTTP authentication.` I spent quite some time  debugging this thinking it might be an authentication issue -- I'm running on a Kerberized cluster).

So, do double check your `job.xml` and `workflow.xml` files.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your **oozie.libpath** declare correctly and exists and you can access the directory 
it should be

```
hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/hive
```